# Ubuntu failure to install on Virtual Box VM

Tags: system-installation, kernel, virtualbox

Started with VirtualBox today, and after downloading the most recent Ubuntu .iso file, I ran the install to my new virtual machine. Everything was going smoothly until the install was nearly complete and it showed an error loading, "linux image," or something to that extend. It ended with what appears to be a terminal screen that I cannot navigate because my cursor disappears on capture. The end line seems to be [    1.148647] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---

No matter what I do it seems to be stuck here. Am I looking at a hardware issue, or is it maybe some corruption in the iso file? I have been working at this all day and I am hamstrung at the finish line. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Virtualbox did you install?  I just installed Virtualbox 7 and I got rid of it and went back to 6.1.  Virtualbox 7 has some issues that still need to be worked out.  VB 6.1 has been suiting me well.

Comment: It is VirtualBox 7. I am starting with increasing the vhd space like someone suggested in another thread and rerunning the install on another machine. If that does not work, I may have to uninstall and revert to an earlier version of VirtualBox. Thanks.